# What is the difference between set symmetric difference and set symmetric difference with mutation in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7

What is the difference between the below two implementations of the set? 

In my case they both are giving the same results.

#### Set Symmetric Difference With Mutation.

```
s = set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
s.symmetric_difference_update(set ([5, 6, 7]))
print s

set([1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7]) #OUTPUT
```

#### Set Symmetric Difference.

```
print set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).symmetric_difference(set([5, 6, 7]))

set([1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7]) #OUTPUT
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're not giving the same results.  You're not doing the same thing.  Try this:

```
s = set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
s.symmetric_difference_update(set ([5, 6, 7]))
print s
```

Versus this:

```
s = set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
s.symmetric_difference(set ([5, 6, 7]))
print s
```

Or, try this:

```
print set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).symmetric_difference_update(set([5, 6, 7]))
```

Versus this:

```
print set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).symmetric_difference(set([5, 6, 7]))
```

See the difference now?

Answer (score 2):

As explained [in the Python Standard Library documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set), `s.symmetric_difference_update(otherset)` updates the original set with the symmetric difference between the two sets, whereas `s.symmetric_difference(otherset)` simply returns the symmetric difference. Compare:

```
In [1]: s = set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

In [2]: s.symmetric_difference(set ([5, 6, 7]))
Out[2]: {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7}

In [3]: print s
set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

In this case, `s` is not changed.